# Difference between similar MiniZinc constraints

Tags: minizinc

In the solution of the Zebra puzzle (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#MiniZinc) there's a constraint stating that one of the pets must be a zebra:

```
var 1..5: n;
constraint Gz[n]=Zebra;
```

Has the expression below a different meaning? They yield different results.

```
constraint exists(n in 1..5)(Gz[n]=Zebra);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These constraints are indeed equivalent. There is however a different in the way MiniZinc will translate these constraint for the solver.

The first option will be translated as a element constraint:

```
var 1..5: n;
constraint array_int_element(n, Gz, Zebra);
```

While the second one will result in an big clause constraint:

```
constraint bool_clause([Gz[1]=Zebra, Gz[2]=Zebra, Gz[3]=Zebra, Gz[3]=Zebra, Gz[5]=Zebra], [])
```

Although the constraints are equivalent it might depend on the solver which form will be more efficient during solving.

A better approach is to use the global `count_leq(array [int] of var int: x, int: y, int: c)` which enforces `c` to be less or equal to the number of occurences of `y` in `x`. Expressing the constraint as:

```
include "count_leq.mzn";
constraint count_leq(Gz, Zebra, 1);
```

directly conveys the meaning of the constraint and allows the solver used to use whichever form of the constraint would be best suited for its solving mechanism

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still studying why the 2nd version of the constraint yields a different result. hakank's answer seems to shed light on it.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly, they might lead to different answer because multiple answers because multiple answers are possible. When the solver gets different (equivalent) models, it might not give the solutions in the same order because its search decisions might not be in the same order. When looking at all solution (`-a`) the solutions should be the same.

Comment: Is setting zero to the value of 'User defined behavior/Stop after this many solutions' within the IDE the same as using the `-a` option? Surprisingly, I get 5 different solutions with said setting.

Comment: Yes, that will result in the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

If the declaration `var 1..5: n` is removed, then there is no global `n` that can be used in the `output` section, and this will yield an error: `MiniZinc: type error: undefined identifier` n'`.

It you keep `var 1..5: n` then the variable `n` in the `exists` loop don't have any effect of the global defined variable `n`, with the result that (the global) `n` will take any of the values 1..5 (which is shown if all solutions are printed).

Comment: When removing `n` from the model, one can still find the value of `n` in the output model by using something like `[i | i in index_set(Gz) where fix(Gz[i]) = Zebra][1]`

Comment: @Dekker1 Good point. And then the original constraint or the exists variant are not really needed.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer, hakank. It seems the usage of `n` is behind the fact that with the 2nd version of the  `Gz[n]=Zebra` constraint a different output is printed out.